# JQuery->Check if group of radios has any selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="InfoCol_1158341_NY" class="InfoCol">
             <td width="50%" id="InfoType_221832" class="TypeCol">
                 <input type="radio" value="221832" name="lt_1158341_221832" id="lt_1158341_221832" class="lt_">
                 <br><label id="lbl_lt_1158341_221832" for="lt_1158341_221832" class="lt_ ">Linse 1<br>Hours: 8</label>
                 <input type="hidden" name="hr_1158341_221832" id="hr_1158341_221832" value="8" class="hr_">
                 <input type="hidden" name="un_1158341_221832" id="un_1158341_221832" value="0" class="un_">
                 <input type="hidden" name="pr_1158341_221832" id="pr_1158341_221832" value="8" class="pr_">
             </td>
             <td width="50%" id="InfoType_221833" class="TypeCol">
                 <input type="radio" value="221833" name="lt_1158341_221833" id="lt_1158341_221833" class="lt_">
                 <br><label id="lbl_lt_1158341_221833" for="lt_1158341_221833" class="lt_ ">Linse 2<br>Hours: 1</label>
                 <input type="hidden" name="hr_1158341_221833" id="hr_1158341_221833" value="1" class="hr_">
                 <input type="hidden" name="un_1158341_221833" id="un_1158341_221833" value="0" class="un_">
                 <input type="hidden" name="pr_1158341_221833" id="pr_1158341_221833" value="1" class="pr_">
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Neither one of the below selectors returns the radios. I need to know if neither one is checked.
Note: PID is passed and value is 1158341

```
$(radio[name^="lt_'+PID+'"]')


$('.TypeCol radio[name^="lt_'+PID+'"]')
```

Can't do it by class because the inputs COULD be hidden vs. radio in this dynamically created form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector:

```
$('input[type=radio][name^="lt_'+PID+'"]')
```

To see if either is checked:

```
if ($('input[type=radio][name^="lt_'+PID+'"]:checked').length > 0) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Some may not be visible, how to only check the visible ones?

Comment: So like this: `$('input[type=radio][name^="lt_'+PID+'"]:checked:visible')`